# Which is the best way of duplicating a table partitioned with hasing in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a partitioned table (using hashing) in a database hosted on PostgreSQL (it's an RDS on AWS).
The table is more or less like this:

```
CREATE TABLE snapshot
(
    url             TEXT         NOT NULL,
    hash_code       VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL,
    ...
    created         TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE (hash_code)
) partition by hash (hash_code);

CREATE TABLE snapshot_1 PARTITION OF snapshot
    FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 0);

CREATE TABLE snapshot_2 PARTITION OF snapshot
    FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 1);

CREATE TABLE snapshot_3 PARTITION OF snapshot
    FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 3, REMAINDER 2);
```

I need to duplicate this table, creating a new one, let's call it **snapshot2**. I would like to copy exactly the same structure, including partitions and data. Which is the fastest way to do it?
Not sure if I can run a statement similar to..

```
create table snapshot2 (like snapshot including all)....
```

I was trying to run the statement above but I didn't manage to make it work.
What I did so far was to create manually the new table and copying data by batches but I was wondering if there is any easier and faster approach.
Thanks a lot